# How do I replace all zeroes in a python list with nothing?

Tags: python

I need to replace the zeros in newsplitted with nothing. Basically, I need to remove them. How do I do this WITHOUT imports? Can Anyone help?

```
input_string = "01-result.xls,2-result.xls,03-result.xls,05-result.xls" 
# Must be turned into ['result1','result2', 'result3', 'result5']

splitted = input_string.split(',')

newsplitted =  ["".join(x.split('.')[0].split('-')[::-1]) for x in splitted ]
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
final = []
for Y in newsplitted :
      final =[Y.replace('0','')]
```

Just for the sake of learning, if I wanted to do the replace part at the end in another for loop, how would one do that????

Comment: Can someone help me do this in a for loop also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A one liner with a list comprehension

```
input_string = "01-result.xls,2-result.xls,03-result.xls,05-result.xls"

result = [''.join(i.split('-')[::-1]).replace('.xls', '').replace('0', '') for i in input_string.split(',')]
```

result

```
['result1', 'result2', 'result3', 'result5']
```

This is essentially the same as

```
result = []
for i in input_string.split(','):
    formatted_element = ''.join(i.split('-')[::-1]).replace('.xls', '').replace('0', '')
    result.append(formatted_element)
```

In your case you should have done this:

```
[Y.replace('0', '') for Y in newsplitted]
```

or

```
final = []
for Y in newsplitted :
      final.append(Y.replace('0',''))
```

i'll suggest you read more about list comprehensions in python

http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/

and you can always refer to the docs

https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: Just for the sake of learning, if I wanted to do the replace part at the end in another for loop, how would one do that????

@danidee

Comment: it would look like this `[element.replace('.xls, ''').replace('0', '') for element in already_formatted_string]`

Comment: Thanks so much, but your still using list comprehension, is there any way of doing this without list comprehensions or imports??? @danidee

I know the PYTHONIC way is the best, but im still curious

Comment: of course...see my updated answer...the key was to use the `append` method of your string and not creating a new list inside your loop with the return value of `str.replace`, it's just a common thing to work on each element in a list and return a new list that's why list comprehensions where invented...you can read the PEP here https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/

Answer (score 1):

Use the builtin [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) method:

```
newsplitted =  ['result01', 'result2', 'result03', 'result05']
result = map(lambda x: x.replace('0', ''), newsplitted)
```

Using **map()** is good practice when you want to do the same thing to every 
item in your iterable.

Answer (score 1):

```
input_string = "01-result.xls,2-result.xls,03-result.xls,05-result.xls" 
result = [el[el.index('-')+1:]+el[el.index('-')-1] for el in input_string.replace(".xls","").split(',')]
```

And the result is :

```
['result1', 'result2', 'result3', 'result5']
```